# Save and remove file

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I want to have functionality in shiny app to download word doc after user enters input in the text area. User will provide input as html. Download button should generate docx file.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6, offset = 3,
           hr(),
           h2('Editor:'),
           textInput('editor1', 'MY TEXT',
                   HTML('<b>Sam</b> <i>Dave</i>'), 
                   ),
           hr(),
           h2('Editor Content:'),
           htmlOutput('editor1_content')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$editor1_content <- renderUI({HTML(enc2utf8(input$editor1))})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If creating a temporary file is an option, we create a file, write the input into it, do the conversion and then remove the file

```
file1 <- file.path(tempdir(), "test.html")
writeLines(text = "<b>Sam</b> <i>Dave</i>", con = file1)
rmarkdown::pandoc_convert(file1, to = "docx", output = "word.docx")
file.remove(file1)
```